# Why does my JS URL string's & get converted to #038; on some server setups?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-escape-characters

I have a HTML select field with options and some JS which builds a URL and adds it as the value of the options:

```
  <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      url = '';
      url += '?test=1'
      url += '&something=1' // Ampersand here becomes #038; on some hosts
      $( '#select option' ).val( url );
    });
    $( document ).on( 'change', '#select', function( e ) {
            window.location = $( this ).val();
        });
  </script>

  <select id="select">
    <option value="">Test</option>
    <option value="">Test</option>
  </select>
```

I've noticed at jsfiddle this works fine, but then when trying this locally it converts the ampersand in `url` to `#038;`

Why is this? As it's doing this it effects me getting `$_GET['something']` via PHP when that option is selected

Comment: Although this question is about wordpress, the answers might be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8511295/13927534

Comment: "*it converts*" - where exactly is this conversion happening? It seems you're writing code, which is then interpreted and/or manipulated by php, emitting html, which is parsed by the browser, the results of which are parsed and executed as javascript, building a js string value, which is put into the DOM and read back using jQuery, assigned to `window.location` which makes the browser send another request to some php code that reads the request options. Where exactly does the unexpected value appear?